# Google Sites HTML removes ID attribute

Tags: jquery-ui, attributes, accordion, google-sites

I am trying to use JQuery's accordion on a Google Sites page.

When trying to assign an ID or class to, say, a  element, Google Site's HTML editor removes those attributes.

So, for instance, I type    and then click Update. Upon returning to the HTML editor, that line of code reads simply   .

Answer (score 0):

You can add Jquery on Google Sites via App Script ( HTML Services )
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#jquery_and_jquery_ui